# R apply code to different factors or levels

Tags: r, apply

Below is code to generate data to demonstrate the problem.

```
con <- textConnection('
  Nu Na Vo
 100  A 60
 103  A 2
 104  A 2
 106  A 5
 107  A 1
 108  A 1
 112  A 50
 100  B 1
 108  B 4
 109  B 2
 120  B 30
 109  C 40
                      ')
tt <- read.table(con, header = T)
close(con)
test <- as.data.frame(tt)
```

I've the following code. It is to assign value to "Sta" column subject to the specific condition and to add the difference in "Nu" between i and i+1 row into "Lag" column.

```
library(dplyr)
# to sort "Na" column and arrange "Nu" in descending order
# in order to apply the code below. 
test2 <- tt %.% arrange(Na, -Nu)
for (i in 1:nrow(test2)) {

  if (i < nrow(test2)) {

    if (test2[i, ]$Nu - 2 > test2[i+1, ]$Nu) {
      test2[i, 4] <- "N"
      test2[i, 5] <- test2[i, ]$Nu - test2[i+1, ]$Nu
    } else if (test2[i, ]$Nu - 2 <= test2[i+1, ]$Nu) {
      test2[i, 4] <- "Y"
      test2[i, 5] <- test2[i, ]$Nu - test2[i+1, ]$Nu
    }

  } else if (i == nrow(test2)) {
    test2[i, 4] <- "N"
    test2[i, 5] <- 0
  }
}
names(test2)[names(test2) == "V4"] <- "Sta"
names(test2)[names(test2) == "V5"] <- "Lag"
test2
```

After running the code, it produces the result as below:

```
    Nu Na Vo Sta Lag
1  112  A 50   N   4
2  108  A  1   Y   1
3  107  A  1   Y   1
4  106  A  5   Y   2
5  104  A  2   Y   1
6  103  A  2   N   3
7  100  A 60   Y -20
8  120  B 30   N  11
9  109  B  2   Y   1
10 108  B  4   N   8
11 100  B  1   Y  -9
12 109  C 40   N   0
```

The values under "Sta" column are properly assigned but not for the "Lag" column. The original intention is to apply the code based on different values/levels in "Na", that is "A", "B", "C".  Don't how to apply the code to "A", "B", "C" separately and combine separate results into ONE table.  Desired outcome should be:

```
    Nu Na Vo Sta Lag
1  112  A 50   N   4
2  108  A  1   Y   1
3  107  A  1   Y   1
4  106  A  5   Y   2
5  104  A  2   Y   1
6  103  A  2   N   3
7  100  A 60   Y   0 << Last row for "A". "Lag" should be "0"; "Sta" should be "N".
8  120  B 30   N  11
9  109  B  2   Y   1
10 108  B  4   N   8
11 100  B  1   Y   0 << Last row for "B". "Lag" should be "0"; "Sta" should be "N".
12 109  C 40   N   0 << Last row for "C". "Lag" should be "0"; "Sta" should be "N".
```

## Edited

Not sure how to apply the code to different factors / levels of "Na": "A", "B" and "C".  Possible to use split() or apply family of functions?  As could see from the result and intent of the code above, the result should be FACTOR / LEVEL / Element dependent (hope I'm using the proper terminology) and will affect values under both "Sta" and "Lag" columns.  However my code could not distinguish this.  Appreciate for any help provided.  Thanks

## An inelegant solution!

For completeness, I post herewith a possible solution.  I code it the hard way.  If anyone could help simplify it, it would be very much appreciated.

```
con <- textConnection('
  Nu Na Vo
 100  A 60
 103  A 2
 104  A 2
 106  A 5
 107  A 1
 108  A 1
 112  A 50
 100  B 1
 108  B 4
 109  B 2
 120  B 30
 109  C 40
                      ')
tt <- read.table(con, header = T)
close(con)
require(dplyr); require(data.table)
test2 <- tt %.% arrange(Na, -Nu)
spl <- split(test2, test2$Na)
spl
for (i in 1:length(levels(test2$Na))) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(spl[[i]])) {

    if (j < nrow(spl[[i]])) {

      if (spl[[i]][j, ]$Nu - 2 > spl[[i]][j+1, ]$Nu) {
        spl[[i]][j, 4] <- "N"
        spl[[i]][j, 5] <- spl[[i]][j, ]$Nu - spl[[i]][j+1, ]$Nu
      } else if (spl[[i]][j, ]$Nu - 2 <= spl[[i]][j+1, ]$Nu) {
        spl[[i]][j, 4] <- "Y"
        spl[[i]][j, 5] <- spl[[i]][j, ]$Nu - spl[[i]][j+1, ]$Nu
      }
    } else if (j == nrow(spl[[i]])) {
      spl[[i]][j, 4] <- "N"
      spl[[i]][j, 5] <- 0
    } 
  }
}
spl <- rbindlist(spl)
setnames(spl, c("V4", "V5"), c("Sta", "Lag"))
spl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ave` to the rescue - if applied twice this will essentially do the same comparisons as your long loop code.

First, calculate the lag differences using diff for each group, and set the value for the last row in each group to 0. Then use the computed lag values to determine the "Sta" column, forcing the last row in each group's value to be assigned "N".

```
test2$Lag <- with(test2, ave(Nu,  Na, FUN=function(x) -c(diff(x),0)) )
test2$Sta <- with(test2, ave(Lag, Na, FUN=function(x) {
             out <- ifelse(x > 2, "N", "Y"); out[length(out)] <- "N"; out}))
```

Same result as requested:

```
test2[c(1:3,5,4)]

#    Nu Na Vo Sta Lag
#1  112  A 50   N   4
#2  108  A  1   Y   1
#3  107  A  1   Y   1
#4  106  A  5   Y   2
#5  104  A  2   Y   1
#6  103  A  2   N   3
#7  100  A 60   N   0
#8  120  B 30   N  11
#9  109  B  2   Y   1
#10 108  B  4   N   8
#11 100  B  1   N   0
#12 109  C 40   N   0
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems this is a quick and dirty way :-)  Would like to know how to make use of the factor or level property under column "Na". If there is a script that could be incorporate into the original body of code would be nice. Possible to use split(), lapply() etc.?

Comment: `ave` uses split internally. Type `ave` and hit enter at the R console to see the code it uses. Notice that `Na` is the second argument to the `ave` call, which is the `factor` passed to `split`.

Comment: Right, but couldn't make use of part of the code which actually is scripted for it:  <br/>`  } else if (i == nrow(test2)) {
    test2[i, 4] <- "N"
    test2[i, 5] <- 0
  }`

Comment: Thank @thelatemail for the solution first.  Actually my question was not clear.  I just edited the question.  Hope language better illustrates the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, I post a possible solution to my question.

Comment: @KFB - I have edited to provide a solution that gives the result you request. It does calculations within each `Na` group, but does away with all the convoluted looping code.